# Are App Store elements (eg app store copy, preview images) perserved when you transfer an app

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, data-transfer

Will I need to re-enter the app store copy, translations, preview images and video when I move an app to a new publisher account, or is that content retained on the app store?
Thanks in advance for any comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is retained when transferring the app.